# Unable to generate R markdown report from VBA

Tags: r, excel, vba, r-markdown

I am trying to create a R markdown PDF document from VBA (don´t get me started regarding why...). I am able to run R scripts from VBA so my idea was to create a R script and then use `rmarkdown::render()` from that script. Unfortunately this does not work for me and I cannot figure out why...

Everything works fine when sourcing the R script from within RStudio. That is, the report is created as it should.

If I comment out the `rmarkdown::render()` line in the RScript, then the R script is executed as it should when being called from VBA.

I have spent quite some time on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

In advance, thanks!
C

---

The R markdown code for `GenerateReportTest.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "XXX"
date: "6/15/2023"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

The code in the R script `GenerateReportTest.R`:

```r
print("1")
Sys.sleep(5)

rmarkdown_path <- "C:/.../GenerateReportTest.Rmd"

rmarkdown::render(rmarkdown_path)

print("2")
Sys.sleep(5)
```

And finally, the VBA sub:

```vb
Sub RunRScript()

    Dim shell As Object: Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim wait_till_complete As Boolean: wait_till_complete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim error_code As Integer
    Dim path_to_rscript As String

    path_to_rscript = "C:\...\GenerateReportTest.R"
    
    error_code = shell.Run("Rscript " & path_to_rscript, style, wait_till_complete)

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to paste all those `¤`s in front of every line?  Or is that just an artifact from the encoding?  On a different note: I can say from personal experience that the intersection of R with VBA is a rabbit hole that could benefit from further exploration.

Comment: I'd guess that there's something on the R side of things which is relying on a specific current directory which is correct when run from RStudio, but is not set to the same location when the script is run from VBA.

Comment: @Greg Yes, I meant to do it as the HTML code in the .Rmd file messed up the looks of my post.

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess you are right. I tried to avoid issues by specifying the whole path, but without luck…

Comment: If @TimWilliams is correct about it being an issue with the "current directory", which is accurate when run in RStudio but not when triggered from VBA, then perhaps the **`this.path`** package would be helpful.  Due to its consistency in any context, I use `this.path::this.dir()` and `this.path::this.path()` whenever I need to "orient" an R script to its own location, and it has never let me down!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this question myself...

The key (for me) was to figure the whole thing out was to add some error handling so that my R script code looked like:

```r
print("1")
Sys.sleep(5)

rmarkdown_path <- "C:/.../GenerateReportTest.Rmd"

tryCatch(
  expr = {
    rmarkdown::render(rmarkdown_path)
  },
  error = function(e){
    message('Caught an error!')
    print(e)
  },
  warning = function(w){
    message('Caught an warning!')
    print(w)
  },
  finally = {
    print("All done!")
  }
)

print("2")
Sys.sleep(15)
```

I got the information that it had something to do with "pandoc" and after some searching I got everything to work by inserting Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\pandoc") in the beginning of the script:

```r
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\bin\\pandoc")

print("1")
Sys.sleep(5)

rmarkdown_path <- "C:/.../GenerateReportTest.Rmd"

tryCatch(
  expr = {
    rmarkdown::render(rmarkdown_path)
  },
  error = function(e){
    message('Caught an error!')
    print(e)
  },
  warning = function(w){
    message('Caught an warning!')
    print(w)
  },
  finally = {
    print("All done!")
  }
)

print("2")
Sys.sleep(15)
```